# Duplicates /Multiple values over data range Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where multiple users have update access.
Table `Point_of_sale` ( `Brand`, `Sub_brand`, `value`, `start_date`, `end_date` )

If user1 updates the `value` to $10 and user2 updates the `value` to $20 without putting end_date on the first record , it creates discrepancy.I need to find out all such values in the table.
Depending on when I'm running this query it should get results for all active records , meaning in below example if I'm running the query in JUN 2021 , the start_date is good for 2 records since it is > 1-JAN-2021 and  5-MAY-2021.

How can I make use of partition by /order by

| Brand | Sub_Brand | Value | START_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Silverware | Spoon | 10 | 1-JAN-2020 | 20-DEC-2020 |
| Silverware | Spoon | 20 | 1-JAN-2021 |  |
| Silverware | Spoon | 30 | 5-MAY-2021 |  |

Expected result of query

| Brand | Sub_Brand | Value | START_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Silverware | Spoon | 20 | 1-JAN-2021 |  |
| Silverware | Spoon | 30 | 5-MAY-2021 |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to want to count the `NULL` values for each brand/sub-brand and then return the `NULL` values when there are more than two:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT p.*,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN end_date IS NULL THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY brand, sub_brand) AS num_null
  FROM   point_of_sale p
)
WHERE  num_null > 1
AND    end_date IS NULL;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
create table Point_of_sale (Brand, Sub_Brand, Value, START_Date, End_Date) AS
SELECT 'Silverware', 'Spoon', 10, DATE '2020-01-01', DATE '2020-12-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Silverware', 'Spoon', 20, DATE '2021-01-01', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Silverware', 'Spoon', 30, DATE '2021-05-05', NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| BRAND | SUB_BRAND | VALUE | START_DATE | END_DATE | NUM_NULL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Silverware | Spoon | 30 | 05-MAY-21 | *null* | 2 |
| Silverware | Spoon | 20 | 01-JAN-21 | *null* | 2 |

If you want rows before today then use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT p.*,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN end_date IS NULL THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY brand, sub_brand) AS num_null
  FROM   point_of_sale p
  WHERE  start_date <= SYSDATE
)
WHERE  num_null > 1
AND    end_date IS NULL;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WC3yFgbn)

Comment: This worked beautifully with all the other zillion conditions that I had include And also runs much faster than the group_by and count which I was using  , TYSM!!